# How can I view the keys and values of an object returned by a query?

Tags: javascript

I query a data in a website using a javascript and the return value was an Object, so my question is how can I view the keys and values returned by the query.

Comment: if you're using firebug, chrome, or opera, you can use `console.log(object);` to inspect the object in the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var prop in object) {
    document.write(prop + ":" + object[prop]);
}
```

You may want to recurse into some fields if they are themselves objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for in loop to iterate a object and see its key values.

`for (variable in object)
  {
  code to be executed
  }`